# Telegram bot send message problems after some days

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I have some problem with my telegram message, it's overview of problem:

You will pass /start command my bot started sending messages, but after some days it will stop sending messages, if client pass some message client bot again starts sending messages, what can I do for define after how much days it will stop, does it documentation anywhere? maybe some configurations are wrong? who have such kind of situation pls, reply?

also I always this api call for sending messages:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{TELEGRAM_BOT}/sendMessage?disable_web_page_preview=false&chat_id=$chat_id&text={TEXT}
```

Comment: You should add more information. Post your code, tell us about your hosting provider. Add anything that might be useful for people to understand your problem.

Answer (score 4):

When a telegram group is migrated to supergroup, the chat id for the group changes. Do check if you are sending your message to the new chat_id.

Answer (score 2):

if user stops the bot you cant send any messages to him/her and you receive a error like this:

```
[Error]: Bot was blocked by the user
```

i use the bots about the beginning and i never saw something like this happens.

Comment: No user doesn't block the bot.

Comment: what do you get on response? if the send process successfully completed you should revive a message object. did you get it? if it happens again try to log the response message.

Comment: Also this is all error types which I detected in my logs: [Error]: Forbidden: bot was kicked from the group chat
[Error]: Bad Request: group is deactivated
[Error]: Bad Request: group chat is migrated to supergroup chat
[Error]: PEER_ID_INVALID
[Error]: Forbidden: can't write to chat with deleted user
[Error]: Bad Request: chat not found
[Error]: Bot was blocked by the user

Comment: But I don't know exactly which one is responds when bot stops the sending message. . . .

Comment: i tell you what to do: if this happened again just send me user ID and bot token.(of course if you want). then i will troubleshoot the case. its the only way come up to me right know.

Comment: I if I detect it, I think I can do fix, but I can't wait that time that's why I asked question, thanks for comments.